# Who initializes the arguments in method executed by @Post (or any jax rs annotations)?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, resteasy, restlet

I saw in the rest service the following code snippet

```
    @POST
    @Consumes("application/xml")
    @Path("/ProjectConfiguration/{onetimetoken}")
    public void createProjectConfiguration(@PathParam("onetimetoken") String oneTimeToken,
            CreateProjectConfigurationRequest request) throws IntegratedAppFault {
        // NOOPS
    }
```

In this value of variable oneTimeToken is initialised by what comes  in path. But my doubt is how  request object of the type CreateProjectConfigurationRequest  is initialized .How are we given freedom to have any parameter in these methods . How this works ? How is it guaranteed that this gets initialised .

Comment: I searched for this and started studying these annotations . I found this link https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html . even here they have used "Printer printer" . But no info of how it is initialized . To see the usage do "Ctrl + F Printer printer"

Comment: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method above is expecting an HTTP POST request with an XML message in the body.  You can tell because the method is annotated with `@POST` and `@Consumes("application/xml")`.  Resteasy sees that you have a `CreateProjectConfigurationRequest` type in your method signature, which is annotated with JAXB annotations, and binds the body of your HTTP request to that object.

You can also inject instances of the following classes using the `@Context` annotation.

1. javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders
2. javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo
3. javax.ws.rs.core.Request
4. javax.servlet.HttpServletRequest
5. javax.servlet.HttpServletResponse
6. javax.servlet.ServletConfig
7. javax.servlet.ServletContext
8. javax.ws.rs.core.SecurityContext

There is standard support built into JAX-RS compliant frameworks for marshalling XML and Json request bodies into method arguments.  If you need to read a custom message format then you would create a `MessageBodyReader` which would take the incoming http request body and bind it to a parameter just like XML or Json.

### Example

The code below illustrates how to bind the request body to a java object in your method parameters.

Using your example above let's assume we have the following rest endpoint exposed by our service:

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/xml")
@Path("/ProjectConfiguration/{onetimetoken}")
public void createProjectConfiguration(@PathParam("onetimetoken") String oneTimeToken,
        CreateProjectConfigurationRequest request) throws IntegratedAppFault 
{
    System.out.println(oneTimeToken);
    System.out.println(request.toString());
}
```

This endpoint is expecting to receive an HTTP POST message containing an XML representation of `CreateProjectConfigurationRequest`.

We know this because:

1. The method is annotated with `@POST` indicating it is triggered by POST requests.
2. The method is annotated with `@Consumes(application/xml)` indicating that it is only triggered by requests with an HTTP `Content-Type` header of `application/xml`.
3. There is a method parameter of `CreateProjectConfigurationRequest` that is not annotated with `@Form`, `@FormParam`, `@PathParam`, `@QueryParam`, or `@HeaderParam` that would indicate it is coming from some other part of the request.

Now, let's assume that `CreateProjectConfigurationRequest` is defined as follows:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class CreateProjectConfigurationRequest 
{
   private int id;
   private String name;

   @XmlElement
   public int getId()
   {
      return id;
   }

   public void setId(int id)
   {
      this.id = id;
   }

   @XmlElement
   public String getName()
   {
      return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name)
   {
      this.name = name;
   }
}
```

Now when we send an HTTP POST request to `http://somehost/someapp/ProjectConfiguration/123abc` with a `Content-Type` of `application/xml` and the following XML body our method will be invoked.

```
<CreateProjectConfigurationRequest>
  <id>123</id>
  <name>test</name>
</CreateProjectConfigurationRequest>
```

The Resteasy JAXB Provider will then take the incoming XML and create a `CreateProjectConfigurationRequest` object based on introspecting the object and the annotations that we added to it above.

Your method will then run and print the oneTimeToken (retrieved from the path using the `@PathParam("onetimetoken")` annotation) and request.

Comment: Thanks for the response . Please can you explain what you mean by "binds the body of your HTTP request to that object"

Comment: @Harish - added an example xml, pojo, and steps of binding

Comment: Is it done by dependency injection ? Is my CreateProjectConfigurationRequest injected here ? why I am asking this question is when I am studying dependency injection this struck me .